# permutation_importance gives me an error: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'feature_names'

Tags: scikit-learn

i get an error when I want to see the permutation_importance of my features. This is my code, I copied it from sklearn page

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(inputs,target,test_size=0.2)
model = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=42)
model = model.fit(X_train, y_train)
model.score(X_test,y_test)

from sklearn.inspection import permutation_importance
r = permutation_importance(model, X_test, y_test,
                           n_repeats=30,
                           random_state=0)

for i in r.importances_mean.argsort()[::-1]:
    if r.importances_mean[i] - 2 * r.importances_std[i] > 0:
        print(f"{inputs.feature_names[i]:<8}"
            f"{r.importances_mean[i]:.3f}"
            f" +/- {r.importances_std[i]:.3f}")
```

Here is the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\Users\Sophia. T\Downloads\Ordner\ai_oma.ipynb Cell 11' in <cell line: 6>()
      6 for i in r.importances_mean.argsort()[::-1]:
      7     if r.importances_mean[i] - 2 * r.importances_std[i] > 0:
----> 8         print(f"{inputs.feature_names[i]:<8}"
      9             f"{r.importances_mean[i]:.3f}"
     10             f" +/- {r.importances_std[i]:.3f}")

File c:\Users\Sophia. T\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py:5575, in NDFrame.__getattr__(self, name)
   5568 if (
   5569     name not in self._internal_names_set
   5570     and name not in self._metadata
   5571     and name not in self._accessors
   5572     and self._info_axis._can_hold_identifiers_and_holds_name(name)
   5573 ):
   5574     return self[name]
-> 5575 return object.__getattribute__(self, name)

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'feature_names'
```

Comment: The problem is in your data, not in permutation importance, probably your data don't have the attribute 'feature_names'. Can you show the data you are working with? Almost any dataframe have the attribute 'feature_names' (except from prepared ones like Boston or Iris). One solution could be try: `inputs.columns[i]` instead of `inputs.feature_names[i]`

Comment: You haven't shown the definition of the (apparently?) dataframe `inputs`. But indeed, dataframes do not have a `feature_names` attribute (see instead `columns`).